How do I have both windows of the same application in the dock?
I recently bought a Mac and since I'm used to having two windows of the same software open next to each other in the Windows taskbar, it's very convenient to click on one and then on the other so that one window overlaps the other and I can use them both on the same monitor expanded to the maximum.
I can't figure out how to do the same thing with the Mac.
The two windows are open to the maximum but to change from one to the other I first have to right-click on the icon in the dock and choose which window I want to come to the foreground.
How do I have both windows of the application in the dock?
I'm on Sequoia OS.

There is no "taskbar" on the Mac. I assume you are speaking of the dock which is usually at the bottom of the screen. Window management in macOS is not the same as Windows. There likely no out of the box setting that will do this without using some third party window management app. You could minimize the window with the yellow (center) button in the upper right of all windows, that will move the window to the right side of the dock as an icon representing the window.

I cannot believe there is no way!

Believe it or not, I personally know no way. Remember that the Mac is not Windows and you will need to get used to the differences. There are a lot of people who have Macs after using Windows, and there may be software out there that does what you want. Just search for it. And like I said above you can minimize windows into the dock (yellow button) which does something very similar to what you seem to be asking.

Use ⌘` (command-backtick) to switch between open windows of the same application.
From https://support.apple.com/en-us/102650

Command–Grave accent (`): Switch between the windows of the app you're
using. (The character on the second key varies by keyboard. It's
generally the key above the Tab key and to the left of the number 1.)


I cannot believe there is no way!
